# variable number of threads

Tags: python, multithreading, threadpool

i want to hav a variable number of threads who run at the same time.
I tested multiple multithread examples from multiprocessing but they dont run at the same time.
To explain it better here an example:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
   print("a",x)
   time.sleep(1)
   print("b",x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   with Pool(3) as p:
       for i in range(5):
           p.map(f, [i])
```

Result:

```
a 0
b 0
a 1
b 1
a 2
b 2
```

Here it does a waits 1 sec and then b, but i want it that all a's get printed first and then b's (That every Thread runs at the same time so that the result looks like this:

```
a0
a1
a2
b0
b1
b2
```

Comment: Please see for the beginning: https://dev.to/nbosco/multithreading-vs-multiprocessing-in-python--63j .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned threads but seem to be using processes. The threading module uses threads, the multiprocessing module uses processes. The primary difference is that threads run in the same memory space, while processes have separate memory. If you are looking to use process library. Try using below code snippet.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time

def f(x):
   print("a",x)
   time.sleep(1)
   print("b",x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   for i in range(5):
       p =  Process(target=f, args=(i,))
       p.start()
```

processes are spawned by creating a Process object and then calling its start() method.

Comment: Thanks, the code works just fine, but i have a question.
How can i "sync" a variable with all Threads?
Example:
`
import time
from multiprocessing import Process
test_variable = 0
def f(x):
    global test_variable
    print("a", x)
    test_variable += 1
    time.sleep(1)
    print(test_variable,"b", x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   for i in range(5):
       p =  Process(target=f, args=(i,))
       p.start()

`

Result:
a 0
a 1
a 2
a 3
a 4
1 b 0
1 b 1
1 b 2
1 b 3
1 b 4

But it should be 
4 b 0
4 b 1...

Comment: I think you meant to use shared counter with multiple processes. I hope this helps
https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/01/04/shared-counter-with-pythons-multiprocessing

Answer (score 1):

First of all this is not a **threads** pool, but a **processes** pool. If you want threads, you need to use `multiprocessing.dummy`.

Second, it seems like you misunderstood the `map` method. Most importantly, it is **blocking**. You are calling it with a single numbered list each time - `[i]`. So you don't actually use the `Pool`'s powers. You utilize just one process, wait for it to finish, and move on to the next number. To get the output you want, you should instead do:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(3) as p:
        p.map(f, range(5))
```

But note that in this case you have a race between the number of processes and the range. If you want all `a`s and only then all `b`s, try to use `Pool(5)`.